# Como insertar varios registros en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo que insertar bastantes campos en una tabla con un campo que tiene que ser consecutivo este se quedo en 60395 por consiguiente debe ser 60396 pero para estar no estar haciendo esto

```
INSERT INTO TransaccionesX (IdTransaccion) VALUES ("6039x")
```

Hasta terminar, quería preguntarles si hay alguna manera de que se inserten varios campos con ese numero consecutivo.

Comment: Con ciclos puedes realizar lo que necesitas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que usar un procedimiento o funcion en SQLserver seclarando variables y un ciclo te dejo un ejemplo y una referencia de donde me base:

```
declare @id int 
select @id = 60395
while @id >=60695 and @id <= 60396
begin
    INSERT INTO TransaccionesX (IdTransaccion) VALUES (@id)
    select @id = @id + 1
end
```

referencia: https://codeday.me/es/qa/20190304/274174.html

Comment: Me funciono a la perfección, solo agregue un id pero ese va fijo así que no tuve problema.

Answer (score 0):

Un ciclo es la peor forma de resolver este problema. Funciona, pero será lento y conflictivo. Una solución ideal sería el uso de una tabla de números. Una tabla de números es simplemente una tabla con una columna de números consecutivos. Aquí dejo un ejemplo de como formar una.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT n
FROM cteTally;
```

Pero obviamente, eso se tiene que integrar a tu INSERT, por lo que quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
INSERT INTO TransaccionesX (IdTransaccion)                         -- Insertamos
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT MAX(idTransaccion) FROM TransaccionesX), 0)  -- El valor máximo
       + n                                                         -- más 1, 2, 3, etc.
FROM cteTally;
```

Otra opción eficiente es utilizar un objeto de secuencia que permite generar números consecutivos. Para esto, también necesitas tener todas las filas necesarias. Ten en cuenta que la creación de la secuencia se realiza una vez, aunque se puede reajustar más adelante.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[SequenciaTransaccionesX] 
 START WITH 60396 
 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Con la secuencia creada, la llamas de la siguiente manera:

```
INSERT INTO TransaccionesX (IdTransaccion)
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[SequenciaTransaccionesX] AS IdTransaccion
FROM AlgunaTabla;
```

Algo que debes tener muy en cuenta, es que la concurrencia hace muy complicado mantener un consecutivo preciso de forma manual y las formas automáticas pueden tener problemas de saltos por transacciones no completadas.